# How do I configure NeoVim to use angularls when working on Angular code?

Tags: neovim, lsp

I work with AngularJS an I'm really missing a good way to navigate the code with NeoVim. I would like to have the same facilities, if possible, that I have using the `angularls` for Angular.

How do I set that up?